# Control an animated gif's frames with a slider bar in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, animated-gif

I have an animated .gif I made (using Pillow) out of individual .png frames I created using pandas/matplotlib reading off a csv. I would like to embed the .gif, or its individual .png frames, in an interactive Jupyter notebook. I want it to be like cell 8 here:

http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-as-interactive-javascript-widgets/

Except cell 8 in the link, the animated does not update until you let go of the mouse button (when you're dragging the progress dot around, that is). I want it to update live as you move the dot. Also, in the link, it seems they are calculating the frames of the animation using a math function... in my case, it's a pre-compiled .gif of frames, nothing is being calculated. I do have the source data, so I suppose I could have the animation read it live, but I imagine just using the .gif I already made would be better for latency reasons, since there would be no real file I/O or math required?

Sorry I don't have any example code, but I am just using the linked article as a starting point but haven't figured out how to extend it to an animated .gif yet.